# Stop shell from interpreting git log output

Tags: git, shell, jenkins

I have a script to generate a changeset on every Jenkins build with the recent commit messages. The problem is that the author name contains \ because it has the domain, so when I write to file, shell inteprets \ as a letter and I don't see the actual `<domain>\<name>`, instead I see something like `<domain><name>`.
My current script is as follows:

```
  git --git-dir=<git dir> log origin/${BUILD_NAME} --since \"$sinceDate\" --graph --oneline --pretty="%h %<(28)%ci %<(20)%an: %s" | while read item
  do
    printf "changeset: $item \r\n" >> //<destination>//change_set_${WEEK_NUMBER_DATE_HOUR}.txt;
  done
```

And as output example, I get something like:

```
changeset: * 0e27e683b 2017-09-26 09:35:16 +0300    SROjohn        : #task #18856
```

instead of

```
changeset: * 0e27e683b 2017-09-26 09:35:16 +0300    SRO\john        : #task #18856
```

Is there a way to stop shell from interpreting the "\"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A POSIX `read` manpage:

> By default, unless the `−r` option is specified, `<backslash>` shall act as an escape character.

Use `read -r item`.

And, as @jthill adds, a constant format string for `printf`:

```
printf 'changeset: %s \r\n' "$item" >> "//<destination>//change_set_${WEEK_NUMBER_DATE_HOUR}.txt"
```

and quote `$BUILD_NAME`.

Comment: Also, use `printf  "changeset: %s \r\n" "$item", `printf` interprets  `%` and ``\`` in the format string...

Comment: @Ryan♦ @jthill Thank you both. It works like a charm :)